# Text Overlapping Images Since iOS9 - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, email, ios9

Background: I build and send Email marketing and since the release of iOS9 all of our customers with this iOS version are experiencing this issue when opening our emails in the Mail App:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC3VU.jpg)

What you can see in the screenshot is the text overlapping the banner which is also overlapping the company logo. It seems that the text loads first then the banner and the text isn't being pushed down when the banner loads.

The code for the header module (with the logo), the banner, and the text module is below

```
<table id="header-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="640" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" style="padding:10px 15px;">
            <table class="deviceWidth" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" align="left">
              <tr>
                <td class="logo" width="300" valign="top" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;">
                    <a rilt="Logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.aaa.com"><img width="300" height="125" border="0" style="display:block;" src="Logo.jpg" alt="aaa" class="deviceWidth" /></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="deviceWidth" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" align="right">
              <tr class="hide">
                <td align="right" style="padding:25px 0px 10px 0px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle" align="right">
                        <a class="telephone" href="tel:1800-555-555" style="color:#58585a; font-size:16px; text-decoration:none;"><img width="25" border="0" style="display:block;" src="/contentlibrary/cell/base/images/phone.png" alt=""/></a>
                      </td>
                      <td valign="middle" align="right" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;font-family:arial;font-size:14px;line-height:14px;color:#B5ADA6;">
                        <a class="telephone" href="tel:1800-500-260" style="color:#B5ADA6; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none;">1800 555 555</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="deviceWidth nav" valign="top" align="right" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;font-family:arial;font-size:11px;line-height:13px;color:#7E7774;">
                  <a rilt="TNavReds" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#7E7774;" href="http://www.cellarmasters.com.au/red-wine?product-type=straight-cases">Chairs</a> | <a rilt="TNavWhites" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#7E7774;" href="http://www.cellarmasters.com.au/white-wine?product-type=straight-cases">Sofas</a> | <a rilt="TNavMixes" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#7E7774;" href="http://www.cellarmasters.com.au/mixed-cases">Shirts</a> | <a rilt="TNavSparkling" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#7E7774;" href="http://www.cellarmasters.com.au/sparkling?product-type=straight-cases">Pants</a> <span class="hide" >| <a rilt="TNavClearance" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#7E7774;" href="http://www.cellarmasters.com.au/wine-clearance">Shoes</a></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="banner-module" width="100%" min-width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="background-color:#E5E0D9;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" align="center">
            <a rilt="TopBanner" href="http://www.aaa.com?utm_link=TopBanner" target="_blank"><img width="640" height="400" border="0" style="display:block;" src="Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" class="deviceWidth"/></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="1col-module-1" width="100%" min-width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
          <td class="copy" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:arial;font-size:13px;line-height:16px;color:#000001;padding:30px 10px 10px 10px;">
            Hi $First_Name$,
            <br /><br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent iaculis luctus elit ornare tempus. Phasellus eget luctus nisi. Mauris vel orci adipiscing, placerat velit nec, laoreet purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam et mi erat.
            <br />
            <br />
            Quisque malesuada massa in mi tristique, tincidunt consequat ligula tempor. Maecenas sollicitudin sem quis ipsum tristique adipiscing. Aenean tincidunt tortor lectus, vel ultricies lectus condimentum ut.
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```